# Can't send data to backend

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to simply send the data to backend to register the user.

**register.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {RegisterService} from './register.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.sass']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registerFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    email: ['', Validators.email],
    password: ['', Validators.pattern('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$')]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private registerService: RegisterService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(inputFields => {
      console.log(this.registerFormGroup.value);
    });
  }

  // Submit the form
  private _onSubmit() {
    // There are some errors
    if (this.registerFormGroup.status === 'INVALID') {
      this.registerFormGroup.markAllAsTouched();
    } else {
      console.log('Ready to send'); // That works!
      // NO errors. Let's register the user
      this.registerService.register(this.registerFormGroup.value);
    }
  }

}
```

**register.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  /**
   * @description Register the user
   * @param data JSON that includes E-Mail and password
   */
  public register(data) {
    return this.http.post('/register', data);
  }
}
```

With `this.registerService.register(this.registerFormGroup.value);` I try to send data to backend but for some reason my server does not get a request. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably [subscribe](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-server)

```js
this.registerService.register(this.registerFormGroup.value)
    .subscribe(response => {
      ...
    });
```

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thank you!